# Python read variable with French characters from file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a set of text files in which variables are stored, which I am trying to read into Python.   As long as the variables do not contain any French characters, e.g. é, ç, etc.  The following piece of code works well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import imp

def getVarFromFile(filename):

    f=open (filename, 'rt')     
        global data
        data = imp.load_source('data', " ", f)
        f.close()

    return()

def main():

    getVarFromFile('test.txt')
    print data.Title
    print data.Language
    print data.Summary

    return()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example output:

```
me@mypc:$ ./readVar.py
Monsieur Flaubert
French
A few lines of text.
```

However when the text file contains French characters, for instance:

```
Title = "Monsieur Flaubert"
Language = "Français"
Summary = "Quelques lignes de texte en Français. é à etc."
```

I am getting the following error for which I cannot find a solution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tag.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "./tag.py", line 22, in main
    getVarFromFile('test.txt')
  File "./tag.py", line 15, in getVarFromFile
    data = imp.load_source('data', " ", f)
  File " ", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file   on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

How can French (utf-8) characters be handled?
Thanks for your consideration and help to this Python-learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

```
data = {}
with codecs.open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Use some logic here to load each line into a dict, like:
        key, value = line.split(" = ")
        data[key] = value
```

This solution doesn't use imp, it requires that you implement your own logic to interpret the contents of the file.